# Configuring different pod configuration for different environments (Kubernetes + Google Cloud or Minikube)

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, cloud-sql-proxy

I have a (containerized) web service talking to an external CloudSQL service in Google Cloud. I've used the sidecar pattern in which a Google Cloud SQL Proxy container is next to the web service and authenticates+proxies to the external CloudSQL service. This works fine. Let's call this Deployment "deployment-api" with containers "api" + "pg-proxy"

The problem occurs when I want to deploy the application on my local minikube cluster which needs to have different configuration due to the service talking to a local postgres server on my computer. If I deploy "deployment-api" as is to minikube, it tries to run the "pg-proxy" container which barfs and the entire pod goes into a crash loop. Is there a way for me to selectively NOT deploy "pg-proxy" container without having two definitions for the Pod, e.g., using selectors/labels? I do not want to move pg-proxy container into its own deployment.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment-api
  namespace: ${MY_ENV}
  labels:
    app: api
    env: ${MY_ENV}
spec:
  replicas: ${REPLICAS}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api
      env: ${MY_ENV}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api
        env: ${MY_ENV}
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pg-proxy
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
        image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.11
        command: ["/cloud_sql_proxy",
          "-instances=<redacted>:${MY_ENV}-app=tcp:5432",
          "-credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/${MY_ENV}-sql-credentials.json"]
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 2  # non-root user
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
        volumeMounts:
          - name: ${MY_ENV}-cloudsql-instance-credentials
            mountPath: /secrets/cloudsql
            readOnly: true
      - name: api
        image: ${DOCKER_IMAGE_PREFIX}api:${TAG}
        imagePullPolicy: ${PULL_POLICY}
        ports:
        - containerPort: 50051
      volumes:
        - name: ${MY_ENV}-cloudsql-instance-credentials
          secret:
            secretName: ${MY_ENV}-cloudsql-instance-credentials
```

Comment: Why does it barf?  Is it because of the volume?

Answer (score 2):

In raw Kubernetes means? No.

But I strongly encourage you to use Helm to deploy your application(s). With helm you can easily adapt manifest based on variables provided for each environment (or defaults). For example with variable `postgresql.proxy.enabled: true` in defaults and

```
{{- if .Values.postgresql.proxy.enabled }}
- name: pg-proxy
...
{{- end }}
```

in helm template you could disable this block completely on dev env by setting the value to false.

Comment: thanks! Yes, I plan to move my cluster deployment management to Helm in the near future.